# Use the activity indicator With ASIHTTPrequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

i'm using ASIHTTPRequest in asynchrone mode and i want to show an Activity Indicator .
In they website they say :

> Disabling automatic updates to the
>   network activity indicator (iOS only)
>
> By default, ASIHTTPRequests will show
>   the network activity indicator (in the
>   status bar) on iOS devices when
>   requests are using the network. If you
>   prefer to manage this yourself, you
>   can disable these updates:
>
> [ASIHTTPRequest
>   setShouldUpdateNetworkActivityIndicator:NO];

But i dont wan't to show it in statuts bar , i disabled the statuts bar in my app . I want to show it in my interface . Some one have an idea ?

Edit : @alex Reynolds, i read and trie it  but my progress bar Still blanc and when finished he become blue directly , he don't progresse .Note that the download take 10 seconde . He still blanc 10 second and then become blue . this is my code

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressView];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

myProgressView is UIProgressView

Comment: Try `[request startSynchronous]` and see if it works. Then work through the queue example for asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ASIHTTPRequest` documentation has a section on [tracking progress](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress) of requests.